# I want to make an ajax driven static site in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My goal is to create a Rails based site that uses AJAX to fetch different sections. The site should never completely refresh. I'm using Rails 3.2.8.

There's a lot of conflicting articles online about how to actually implement this. It seems to me that simply fetching pages.json and using javascript would accomplish my goal, but is that the "rails" way?

Every page that is users will see is static. I'll be using Rails as an admin to CRUD them, but that's it, and that portion doesn't need to be AJAX.

Comment: you might also want to checkout ember.js - https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+and+ember.js

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).  For an ajax heavy site, that's exactly what you need to help organize your code and keep your front end consistent with your database.  Also, check out [this excellent railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1) on implementing backbone in a rails project.

I noticed that you said static site.  Well, if the site is completely static, why bother with something like rails?  I would suggest just coding it in html and javascript because rails is intended to be used for dynamic, database driven sites.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm just redoing my portfolio in Rails before I move to more dynamic projects.